# Flutter How i can call TextFormField onTap or onChanged like onFieldSubmitted when change textfield by click on Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I have an issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86712 but not helpful for me and i can not working well with it. So i hope that can handle onChanged event it same with onFieldSubmitted that when i click to another TextFormField text or number will not be double. Or handle onTap event when change focus to another TextFormField, onFieldSubmitted of TextFormField before will be called. This problem only on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
TextField(
                      controller: _topicController,
                      onChanged: (String v) {
                        setState(() {
                          _topicButtonsDisabled = v.isEmpty;
                        });
                      })
```

Comment: Seem you not understand my problem. my problem that character will be double on windows when i click to another textfield without submitted textfield